# How to make a bot for kick that scans the chatlogs and send a message in my name

Tags: session-cookies

Where can i find my session cookie for the site kick.com and am i even able to just run my bot with my session and is this cookie perm? key?
There are some channels out there where u can get points for being active in chat and type a specific word from time to time. These points can get exchanged for real money, not much but some
so i just want it to run in background

```
import requests
import time

# Cookie-Wert setzen
cookie_value = ""

# Funktion zum Senden einer Nachricht
def send_message(message):
    url = "https://kick.com/channelname/chatroom"  # URL des Kick-Chats
    headers = {
        "Cookie": f"kick_session={cookie_value}"  # Setze das Cookie im Header
    }`youttext`
    data = {
        "message": message
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Nachricht erfolgreich gesendet:", message)
    else:
        print("Fehler beim Senden der Nachricht:", response.status_code)

# Endlosschleife zum Senden von Nachrichten in regelmäßigen Abständen
while True:
    message = input("Gib die Nachricht ein, die du senden möchtest: ")
    send_message(message)
    time.sleep(10)  # Wartezeit zwischen den Nachrichten (in Sekunden)
```